# Embed youtube blinks in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, iframe, youtube

I have a problem.
My youtube videos are 'blinking' while page is loading. I don't know why.
I'm using [embed] shortcode from wordpress.
Here is live example: http://velomelon.com/2016/09/25/times-square-2/
Do you know what is wrong here?

Thank you for help

PS
We are in the way now, so my responses can be delayed...

Comment: It's blinking because it appears to be loading twice (actually maybe four times). What happens if you disable Jetpack temporarily out of curiosity?

Comment: I disabled it for a w few minutes. Problem still occurs. Somehow [embed] shortcode force webrowser to refresh whole page...

Comment: I am pretty sure that my theme is doing this. If I enable Twenty fourteen everything is fine, but I don't do anything with iframe/youtube on purpose...

Comment: It is this bug - https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1836